# How to pass more parameters in useInfiniteQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I am using React query `useInfiniteQuery` to get more data

```
const { data, isLoading, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, error, isFetching } =
useInfiniteQuery("listofSessions", listofSessions, {
  getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
    if (lastPage.length < 10) return undefined;
    return pages.length + 1;
  },
});
```

API requests:

```
const listofSessions = async ({ groupId, pageParam = 1 }) =>
  await axios
    .get(`${apiURL}/groups/allsessions`, {
      params: {
        groupId: 63,
        page: pageParam,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data.data;
    });
```

I want to pass `groupId` to `listofSessions` API function like that:

```
const { data, isLoading, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, error, isFetching } =
    useInfiniteQuery("listofSessions", listofSessions({groupId}), ....
```

But I get an error

> Missing queryFn

How can I solve this problem of passing multiple parameter values in `useInfiniteQuery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does passing a new function work?

```
const listofSessions = async ({ groupId, pageParam = 1 }) =>
  await axios
    .get(`${apiURL}/groups/allsessions`, {
      params: {
        groupId: 63,
        page: pageParam,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data.data;
    });

// pass a new function
const { data, isLoading, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, error, isFetching } =
useInfiniteQuery("listofSessions", ({ pageParam = 1 }) => listofSessions({ groupId, pageParam}), {
  getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
    if (lastPage.length < 10) return undefined;
    return pages.length + 1;
  },
});
```

Edit: Please include dependencies in the query key `InfiniteQuery(["listofSessions", groupId, moreSearchParams],` so that the cache is valid for the search parameters. Thanks @TkDodo for pointing it out and improving the answer

If it is possible to refer to `groupId` inside `listofSessions` that would be a simpler solution.

Comment: please make sure to include all dependencies (`groupId`) in the queryKey!